# Executing windows batch command in Jenkins keeps failing with Exit-1 state

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins

I am testing out "**Jenkins ver. 2.89.4**" in Windows10 Machine and I have configured a simple job to test out few things. Under Build section in Jenkins, I have used "**Execute Windows Batch Command**" and used the following two commands. Both the below commands executes fine in the command prompt but however the Jenkins Build job keeps getting failed with Exit 1 state.

```
date
echo "SampleBuild job completed successfully."
```

Couldn't able to get the reason for the failure. And the following is what we see in console output.

Started by user Administrator
Building in workspace C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\workspace\SampleBuildJob
[SampleBuildJob] $ cmd /c call C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\jenkins6658106255890809140.bat

```
C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\workspace\SampleBuildJob>date
The current date is: Fri 02/23/2018 
Enter the new date: (mm-dd-yy) 
C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\workspace\SampleBuildJob>echo "SampleBuild job completed successfully." 
"SampleBuild job completed successfully."

C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\workspace\SampleBuildJob>exit 1 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Can anyone tell me, what am I missing?

Comment: Please add the `/T`option to the `date` command to suppress it asking for setting the new date on the command line. Maybe that`s the reason for your failing command.

Comment: You do not want to use a command that is going to prompt for input.  `date /T` will suppress the output.  The other option is `echo %date%`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add `(call )` to end of your Batch Command.

This will clear the errorlevel environment variable, there for force the build result to be successful.

If you want to check a specific command's result to determine the build result. Let's say you want to check `dates` command.

```
(dates) || (exit %errorlevel% )
```

This will fail the build if error happens in the first command.
or

```
(dates) && (echo "command executed succesfully!")
```

This will show the message only when the first command successfully executed.

Then with the changed command, you do not need `(call )` any more.

Comment: No it still fails with (call), could you try to give me an example and also explain bit in detail on why the failure happens?

Comment: there is a space after call and before the right parentheses. That code will force the exit code to 0.

Comment: Any luck? please let me know the result. You said you tried (call) but I asked you to try (call ). Remember space matters in Batch.

Comment: But then it forces the result to exit with code 0. It doesn't even check whether it is a true success build.I am trying to understand what is wrong with the above commands and why does it give exit code 1 even when the results are successful. The solution which you have given forces the results to end with exit code 0 irrespective of the result.

Comment: If there are any error occurs before the (call ) is called, the build result will still be failed. The (call ) is only clearing value in the system environment variable "errorlevel". you can try to echo %errorlevel% to check that variable value after each step.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. Please have a look at my recent [build status](https://dpaste.de/uMWP). And before the (call ) there has been a failure and still the build got completed as successful.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my statement is wrong about "any error occurs before the (call ) is called, the build result will still be failed".

Comment: Sorry, I do not have windows environment right now, and made a grammar mistake in the code. Already fixed it, would you please try again?

Comment: Would you please try again? I failed to find a windows env in a short time. So I simplified the command.

Comment: how about removing the /b option? why the errorlevel was 0? If it keeps as 0, just exit 1 or something other than 0, instead of exit the variable.

Comment: Thanks. This solved the issue for me as well! I simply but (call ) at the end of the batch file and now my jenkins script passes.

Answer (score 1):

This windows batch script will work:

```
echo %DATE%
echo %Time%
echo "command executed succesfully!"
```

Answer (score 1):

The windows batch script show the same error to me.
Finally i have added exit 0 at the end it worked